# How can I pause Perl processing without hard-coding the duration?

Tags: perl, dynamic, duration

I have a Perl script that contains this code snippet, which calls the system shell to get some files by SFTP and unzip them with WinZip:

```
#  Run script to get files from remote server
system "exec_SFTP.vbs";

#  Unzip any files that were retrieved
foreach $zipFile (<*.zip>) {
    system "wzunzip $zipFile";
}
```

Even if some files are retrieved, they are never unzipped, because by the time the files are retrieved and the SFTP connection is closed, the Perl script has already completed the unzip step, with the result that it doesn't find anything to unzip.

My short-term fix is to insert

```
sleep(60);
```

before the unzip step, but that assumes that the SFTP connection will finish within 60 seconds, which may sometimes be a gross over-estimate, and other times an under-estimate.

Is there a more sound way to cause Perl to pause until the SFTP connection is closed before proceeding with the unzip step?

Edit:  Responders have questioned (and reasonably so) the use of a VB script rather than having Perl do the file transfer.  It has to do with security -- the VB script is maintained by others and is authorized to do the SFTP.

Comment: Why do the archives have to be unzipped immediately after they are downloaded? Can you download first and then extract after all the files are done?

Comment: That is certainly an option, and may in fact be the best solution if I cannot change the VB script and cannot get my Perl script authorized to SFTP to/from the server.
  But I was also curious about not only the "how" but also the "why," and I think that Michael Carman has correctly diagnosed the cause and neatly summed it up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the code in your *.vbs file. The `system` function waits for the child process to finish before execution continues. It appears that your *.vbs file is forking a background task to do the FTP and returning immediately.

Answer (score 6):

In a perfect world your script would be rewritten to use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP::Foreign) and [Archive::Extract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Extract)..

An ugly quick-hackish kind of way might be to create a touch-file before your first system call, alter your sftp-fetching script to delete the file once it is done and have a while like so

```
while(-e 'touch.file') {
    sleep 5;
}

# foreach [...]
```

Of course, you would need to take care if your .vbs fails and leaves the touchfile undeleted and many other bad side effects. This would be for a quick solution (if none of the other suggestions work) until you get the time to rewrite without system() calls.

Answer (score 4):

You need a way for Perl to wait until the SFTP transfer is done, but as your script is currently written, Perl has no way of knowing this.  (It looks like you're combining at least two scripting languages and a (GUI?) SFTP client; this can work, but it's not exactly reliable or robust.  Why use VBscript to start the SFTP transfer?)

I can think of four options:

1. Your Perl script could do the SFTP transfer itself, using something like CPAN's [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/~dbrobins/Net-SFTP-0.10/) module, rather than spawning an external job whose status it cannot track.
2. Your Perl script could spawn a command-line SFTP utility (like [PSFTP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) that doesn't return until the transfer is done.
3. Or change exec_SFTP.vbs script to not return until the transfer is done.
4. If you're currently using a graphical SFTP client and can't switch for whatever reason, I'd recommend using a scripting language like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) instead of Perl.  AutoIt has features to wait for windows to change state and so on, so it could more easily monitor for an activity's completion.

Options 1 or 2 would be the most robust and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can suggest is modifying exec_SFTP.vbs to exit only after the file transfer is complete.   `system`  waits for the program it called to complete, so that should solve your problem:

```
       system LIST
       system PROGRAM LIST
               Does exactly the same thing as "exec LIST", except
               that a fork is done first, and the parent process
               waits for the child process to complete.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the vbs script to stay alive until it terminates, you may be able to track subprocess creation.  If you get subprocess ids, you can monitor them thereby know when the vbs' various offspring terminate.

[Win32::Process::Info](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Process-Info/lib/Win32/Process/Info.pm) lets you get a subprocess ids from a running process.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a dumb question, but why not just use the [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Net-SFTP-0.08/lib/Net/SFTP.pm) and [Archive::Extract](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html) Perl modules to download and unzip the files?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.1/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm)

> IPC::Open3 - open a process for reading, writing, and error handling using open3()

Answer (score 0):

[`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) will not return until the shell it's running the command in has returned; this may be wrong for launching graphical programs and file associations.

See if any of the following help?

```
system('cscript exec_SFTP.vbs');

use Win32::Process;
use Win32;
Win32::Process::Create(my $proc, 'wscript.exe',
        'wscript exec_SFTP.vbs', 0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, '.');
$proc->Wait(INFINITE);
```